# Stop firebase emulators gracefully when docker stop

Tags: firebase, docker, firebase-tools

My Dockerfile installs firebase emulators. When stop firebase emulators, it should export data before exit.

```
# Skip installation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure

CMD ["firebase", "emulators:start", "--import=./data", "--export-on-exit"]
```

If I run `docker run -ti --name my-firebase-tools my-firebase-tools` and then press Crtl-C, firebase emulators stops gracefully before container stops. Everything is ok.

[image]

But normally, I want to run `docker run -d -ti --name my-firebase-tools my-firebase-tools`, so the container will run in background.

In this case, if I run `docker stop my-firebase-tools`, no signal is sent to firebase to terminal firebase emulators, therefore no data is exported. Container stops after 10s with **exit code 137**.

`docker run -d -ti --stop-signal SIGINT --name my-firebase-tools my-firebase-tools` doesn't help.

Tried with entrypoint.sh below:

```
pid=0

sigterm_handler() {
  if [ $pid -ne 0 ]; then
    kill -SIGTERM "$pid"
    wait "$pid"
  fi
  exit 143; # 128 + 15 -- SIGTERM
}
trap 'kill ${!}; sigterm_handler' SIGTERM

firebase emulators:start --import=./data --export-on-exit &
pid="$!"

# wait forever
while true
do
  tail -f /dev/null & wait ${!}
done
```

the signal is trapped, sigterm_handler is called, but firebase still doesn't receive the termination signal.

Answer (score 4):

This entrypoint solve the problem.

```
#!/bin/bash

loopPid=0
pid=0

sigterm_handler() {
  pkill -P "$pid"
  wait "$pid"
  echo "sigterm handled gracefully"
  exit 0;
}
trap 'sigterm_handler' SIGTERM

sigint_handler() {
  wait "$pid"
  wait "$loopPid"
  echo "sigint handled gracefully"
  exit 0;
}
trap 'sigint_handler' SIGINT

exec firebase emulators:start --import=./data --export-on-exit &
pid="$!"

# wait forever
tail -f /dev/null &
loopPid="$!"
wait "$loopPid"

echo "Not a gracefully shutdown"
exit 1;
```

Comment: Hey, can you please explain this a little more? I am a beginner and don't know about entrypoint much. I am using docker-compose and it does not export on exit.

Comment: We want to run firebase emulator with this command `firebase emulators:start --import=./data --export-on-exit`.

But when docker container stops, it doesn't wait for the export process of firebase emulator inside it.

Therefore, we need to run a more complex script to handle termination signal when we start the docker container.

To run this script, add `ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]` to your `Dockerfile`. The content of `entrypoint.sh` is the script in my answer above.